# What is the difference between Advisor and Aspect in AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am new to Spring AOP. Based on my understanding, I noticed that both Advisor (for example `DefaultPointcutAdvisor`) and Aspect (for example the class annotated with `@Aspect`) can both help to solve the cross-cutting problem by doing something more when a method is invoked.

What is the different between these two term please?

Comment: Old question used Advice vs Aspect Comparison, which is legit and different from Advisor vs Aspect comparison : 
Advice – Indicate the action to take either before or after the method execution.
Pointcut – Indicate which method should be intercept, by method name or regular expression pattern.
Advisor – Group ‘Advice’ and ‘Pointcut’ into a single unit, and pass it to a proxy factory object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most aspects are a *combination of advice* that defines the
aspect’s behavior and a *pointcut* defining where the aspect should be executed.

Spring recognizes this and offers advisors, which combine advice and pointcuts
into one object.

More specifically, the `PointcutAdvisor` does this.

```
public interface PointcutAdvisor {
   Pointcut getPointcut();
   Advice getAdvice();
}
```

Most of Spring’s built-in pointcuts also have a corresponding `PointcutAdvisor`.
This is convenient if you want to define a pointcut and the advice it is managing
in one place.

Read more in [Spring in Action, 3rd Edition](http://unpherum.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/manning-spring-in-action-3rd-edition-jun-2011.pdf)

Sanpshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are they actually substitute to each other?

Comment: I am looking in the source code of Spring and in PointcutAdvisor interface I only see getPointcut() method and not the getAdvice() ?

Comment: I am irritated that this answer was accepted because it answer does not explain why both advisors and aspects exist in Spring, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25094033/1082681) does though. What is said about advisors (being combinations of advice + pointcut) is also true for aspects, only an aspect is much more flexible and can contain multiple pointcuts and/or advices.

Comment: Please raise your concern to book writer of "Spring in action" if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Advisors seem to be an old "AOP lite" type of defining cross-cutting concerns from Spring 1.2 when Java 5 usage was still somewhat uncommon and thus @AspectJ syntax (via Java annotations) not used in Spring. The concept has still survived for lovers of schema-based AOP rather than annotation-based AOP or pure AspectJ syntax, see [Spring documentation on advisors](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-schema-advisors).

> The concept of "advisors" comes from the AOP support defined in Spring and does not have a direct equivalent in AspectJ. An advisor is like a small self-contained aspect that has a ***single*** piece of advice. The advice itself is represented by a bean and must implement one of the advice interfaces described in Advice Types in Spring. Advisors can take advantage of AspectJ pointcut expressions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it clearly responds to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

In my understanding, Aspect is just Aspect Oriented Programming jargon and Advisor is Spring Framework jargon.

Maybe this simple example will be helpful:

**Foo.java**

```
public interface Foo {
    void foo();
    void baz();
}
```

**FooImpl.java**

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo!");
    }

    @Override
    public void baz() {
        System.out.println("Baz!");
    }
}
```

**MethodBeforeAdviceBarImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodBeforeAdviceBarImpl implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Bar!");
    }
}
```

and finally **App.java**

```
import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MethodBeforeAdvice advice = new MethodBeforeAdviceBarImpl();

        final NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor nameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor = new NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor();
        nameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor.setMappedName("foo");
        nameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor.setAdvice(advice);

        final ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.addAdvisor(nameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor);

        final Foo foo = new FooImpl();
        proxyFactory.setTarget(foo);

        final Foo fooProxy = (Foo) proxyFactory.getProxy();
        fooProxy.foo();
        fooProxy.baz();
    }
}
```

Running the **main** method in **App.java** will output:

```
Bar!
Foo!
Baz!
```

So as you see here NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor is an **Advisor** and it consists of a **mappedName**, which is the **pointcut** and the Advice itself, which in this case is **MethodBeforeAdvice**.

And in Aspect Oriented Programming Jargon, an Aspect is Advice + Pointcut, so there you go.. An Advisor seems to be an Aspect after all..

Comment: Great Explanation

Answer (score 1):

`Advice` is the way you take an action on your `Pointcut`. You can use before, after or even around advice to apply any action you defined. Talking about Spring `Aspect`, it is only a class which is a high level and merge two concepts : `joinpoint` and `advice`. It can be done through XML based blueprint, or programmatically. Also you should specify your point where you want to plug in an aspect, it is done by using `Joinpoint`.

Also Spring `Aspects` and `Advice` aren't substitute for each other, because Aspects is only merger for joinpoint and advice.

---